# Issue with PHP JSON encoding missing Object

Tags: php, arrays, json

I am creating a script that passes on some json formatted data. I'm having a issue encoding it correctly. Below is my code:

```
$data = array("email" => "theemail@email.com");

$data_string = json_encode(array('profiles' => $data));

$ch = curl_init('https://theurlisHere');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string))
);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);

//execute post
$result = curl_exec($ch);

//close connection
curl_close($ch);

echo $result;
```

I need my json to look like this:

```
"profile": [
    {
        "email": "theemail@email.com"
    }
]
```

I can't figure out how to get the 'profile' object in to the array.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `$json = json_encode(array('profile'=>array($data)));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
json_encode(array('profile' => array($data)));
```